# List recent non-recurring calendar events

Tags: ios, automation, shortcuts-app

I'm trying to build a shortcut that will show me a list of my ad-hoc non-recurring calendar events to help remind me what I've achieved when preparing quarterly reviews.

I can use `Find Calendar Events Where` to restrict to an appropriate calendar and time window but how can I identify the recurring ones and filter those out?

As a fall back I thought about maintaining a meeting subjects to blacklist but how do I implement that in Shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to check wether calendar events are recurring or not.
Therefore the only way to implement this is by checking for duplicate event-titles.

To implement this, you first have to create a list of all calendar events. Now you have to check for every event-title how often it appears in this list. 
In the end you can add every title that only appears once to a separate list.

Now you should have a list of everything you achieved (only the non-recurring events).

Comment: You have to keep in mind, that this could lead to a problem if you have non-recurring events with the same title. They would also be removed from the list.